# Vuetify - v-simple-checkbox prevents v-data-table row.click event

Tags: vuetify.js, v-data-table

When `v-simple-checkbox` is used in `v-data-table`, clicking on the checkbox or the area around it doesn't invoke `row.click` event.

This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/toni-birka/pen/BapoqZz) example shows selecting a data table row on `row.click`. However, if more columns with checkboxes are used it's almost impossible to select a row.

It seems like the `.stop` event handler is used inside `v-simple-checkbox`. Is there any way to trigger `row.click` event by clicking on that component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the last column of checkboxes are just for display, you can just use a `v-icon` to render the correct checkbox icon.

```
<template v-slot:item.glutenfree="{ value }">
    <v-icon>
        {{ value ? 'mdi-checkbox-marked' : 'mdi-checkbox-blank-outline' }}
    </v-icon>
</template>
```